# How to concatenate values for duplicate hash keys in Perl?

Tags: perl

I know it is not possible to have duplicate keys in a hash, but this is what my data looks like:

```
Key                Value

SETUP_FACE_PROT    great
SETUP_FACE_PROT    great2
SETUP_FACE_PROT    great3
SETUP_FACE_PROT    great3
SETUP_ARM_PROT     arm
SETUP_FOOT_PROT    foot
SETUP_FOOT_PROT    foot2
SETUP_HEAD_PROT    goggle
```

I would like to concatenate values for repeated keys, separated by a `*` character. For example, this is what I want the output to look like:

```
SETUP_FACE_PROT'=great*great2*great3',
SETUP_ARM_PROT='arm',
SETUP_FOOT_PROT='foot*foot2',
SETUP_HEAD_PROT='google'
```

This is how I've tried to solve the problem so far:

```
foreach my $key ( sort keys %stuff ) 
{
   print "$key=\'", join( "*", @{ $stuff{$key} } ), "\'\n";
}
```

But instead of printing the result, how can I store it in a variable so that I can pass it to another subroutine? I'm trying to create a new string that looks like this:

```
$newstring="
SETUP_FACE_PROT='great*great2*great3',
SETUP_ARM_PROT='arm',
SETUP_FOOT_PROT='foot*foot2',
SETUP_HEAD_PROT='google'  "
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't duplicate keys, you can create a hash of arrays.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %stuff;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $key, $value ) = split;
    push( @{ $stuff{$key} }, $value );
}

print Dumper \%stuff;

foreach my $key ( sort keys %stuff ) {
    print "$key=\'", join( "*", @{ $stuff{$key} } ), "\'\n";
}

__DATA__
SETUP_FACE_PROT great
SETUP_FACE_PROT great2
SETUP_FACE_PROT great3
SETUP_FACE_PROT great3
SETUP_ARM_PROT arm
SETUP_FOOT_PROT foot
SETUP_FOOT_PROT foot2
SETUP_HEAD_PROT goggle
```

Edit:

Turning it into a string as requested:

```
my $results; 
foreach my $key ( sort keys %stuff ) {
    $results .= "$key=\'". join( "*", @{ $stuff{$key} } ). "\'\n";
}

print $results;
```

Or perhaps using `print` still with a filehandle:

```
my $results; 
open ( my $output, '>', \$results ); 
foreach my $key ( sort keys %stuff ) {
    print {$output} "$key=\'", join( "*", @{ $stuff{$key} } ), "\'\n";
}
close ( $output );
print $results;
```

Comment: But i want to return that variable instead of printing .any idea.and how to store this in variable.whole result.

Comment: Return it where? This produces the output as in your question. You don't give any more detail, so I can't answer.

Comment: agreed .actually what i was saying was instead of printing :

Comment: "$key=\'", join( "*", @{ $stuff{$key} } ), "\'\n"; i wannt] to store this in variable .so that end result i will get is :SETUP_FACE_PROT = 'great*great2*great3',SETUP_FACE_PROT='arm',SETUP_FOOT_PROT='foot*foot2',SETUP_HEAD_PROT='google'

Comment: If you've further clarification of the desired output, then it's best edited into your question.

Comment: It is in a variable. It's in `%stuff`.

Comment: @Sobrique: `chomp()` within the while loop is not really needed, right?

Comment: @jreisinger no, not really. Seems to work ok without it.

Comment: Updated with inserting into a string. I don't really think you want to stringify and then pass it though, that's kinda ugly.

Answer (score 0):

At last i got an answer doing this.

```
   use Data::Dumper;
   my %stuff;
   use Text::CSV;
   my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, eol => $/ });

   my $filenamex = 'duplicate2.csv';

   $checkstring ='';
    open(my $datab, '<', $filenamex) or die "Could not open '$filename' $!\n";
    $i=1;
    my %datan;
    while (my $linea = <$datab>) 
    {
      chomp $linea;
      @fieldsx = split ",",$linea;
      $key = $fieldsx[0];
      $value = $fieldsx[1];
     # print $key;
       push( @{ $stuff{$key} }, $value );
    }



 foreach my $key ( sort keys %stuff ) 
  {
   $checkstring = $checkstring.','.$key.'='. join( "*", @{ $stuff{$key} } );
  }

 print $checkstring;
```

Comment: Why do you load Text::CSV, create a Text::CSV parser object and then not use it? Also, Sobrique's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34153767/7231) is a much cleaner version of this code. Why not use that instead?

Comment: OK. Updated the answer to include a single variable containing the data.